# Numpy arrays for dearpygui image data

Tags: numpy, dearpygui

I've seen mention of dearpygui as a high performance GUI for Python, and I'm trying to use dearpygui as a high frame-rate image display for simulation data in 2 dimension numpy arrays.

Looking at the dearpygui documentation, I can't find any way to pass a numpy ndarray into a dearpygui texture without first converting it into a list ofnumbers.

Is there a way to load a dearpygui texture (or other dearpygui image-like object) directly from a numpy ndarray without first copying the data into a Python list object?

I did find an old discussion in the API's issues list (#698) concerning numpy images, but hte "add_texture" function in that example (from 2021) doesn't seem to be in the API today.

Clarifying my post to address the question asked below:
What I need to avoid is any operations that manipulate the image data in python as individual values. I realize it is easy to convert a numpy array into a python list, but that involves iterating through the several million values in a python rather than staying in vectorized operations implemented in C in Numpy.

Comment: What do you mean by "list of numbers"?   A numpy array is essentially a "list of numbers".  Do you just need to convert it to a list?

Comment: Responding to Tim Roberts - I need to avoid the time taken by the non-vectorized operation to create a python list from numpy data.  I can't find any way to pass the vectorized numpy object to dearpygui.  I'm looking at this API to see whether it might be a faster alternative to pygame or PIL/tkinter - but neither of those require such a conversion.

Comment: Well, what do you need?  Numpy has ways to get pointers to its internal buffers, assuming the values are the right size and are stored in the right order.  If they aren't, then you have no choice but to reorganize it.

Comment: Thanks Tim - my question is specific to whether the dearpygui package can take a Numpy input - not an issue about Numpy itself.  I actually have a reasonably fast  array display class implemented using Ppygame's surfarray which handles a 2000x1500 numpy array (monochrome) in about 7.5ms, and I'm trying to see whether dearpygui might be still faster.

Comment: My GUESS is this isn't going to be trivial.  Dearpygui is a rather thin wrapper around the C++ guts, but even that wrapper seems to demand a list of float or a tuple of float.

Comment: Thanks again... that was what I saw too, but I was hoping for an option that I hadn't found.  Based on your last note, I've looked at some of the other python bindings to imgui, but that will take a bit of digging!  I'm going to leave the question open in case anyone else sees it who is aware of other options within dearpygui.